# Connection Pooling Library used in Pentaho

Tags: java, pentaho, connection-pooling, pentaho-data-integration

While adding datasource, we can enable connection pooling in Pentaho. We can even provide connection pooling properties, all I want to know is what library (BoneCP, Apache DBCP, CP30, Hikari or something else )  Pentaho 5 uses for connection pooling?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting! care to provide a comment?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but isn't that just a property of the (JDBC) driver being used?

Comment: I guess, JDBC driver can be used with any of the above options for connection pooling. All I wanted to know was which one among those is used by Pentaho.

Comment: I think it uses DBCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho 5 uses DBCP-1.4 for connection pooling. I came to know about it about looking into \biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\lib, there was commons.dbcp jar was available.

@Alpana, was right.